# How to implement Vibrance Effect from Photoshop with OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, photoshop, opencv

Is there a way to do this in C++ or Python? I've tried looking for the theory behind it or any code implementation, but didn't find anything sustainable.

Comment: This looks applicable... https://www.photo-mark.com/notes/analyzing-photoshop-vibrance-and-saturation/

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've already looked through this site, but it just helped me to visualize what's happening behind the curtains. As for the implementation i'm increasing values with saturation value below 150 proportionally (e.g. `S: 149`, then `S = 149*1.01`. `S: 50`, then  `S = 50*1.67`)